# Trigger puppet run on update of manifest / facts

Tags: puppet

I'm working on a tool which manages WordPress instances using puppet. The flow is the following: the user adds the data of the new WordPress installation in the web interface and then that web interface is supposed to send a message to the puppet master to tell it to deploy it to the selected machine.

Currently the setup is done via a manifest file which contains the declaration of all WordPress instances, and that is applied manually via `puppet apply` on the puppet agent. This brings me to my 2 questions:

- Are manifests the correct way of doing this? If so, is it possible to apply them from the puppet master to a specific node instead of going to the agent?
- Is it possible to automatically have a puppet run triggered once the list of instances is altered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes there's absolutely a way of doing this via a puppetmaster, what you have at the moment is a masterless setup which assumes you're distributing your configuration with some kind of version control (like git) or manual process. This is a totally legitimate way of doing things if you don't want a centralized master.

If you want to use a master, you'll need to drop your manifest in the $modulepath of your master (it varies depending on your version, you can find it using `puppet config print modulepath` on your master) and then point the puppet agent at the master.

If you want to go down the master route, I'd suggest following the [puppet documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/post_install.html#configure-a-puppet-master-server) which will help you get started.

The second question brings me on to a philosphical argument of 'is this really want you want to do?'

Puppet traditionally (in my opinion) is a declarative config management tool that is designed to make your systems look a certain way. You write code to determine 'this is how I want it to look' and Puppet will converge to make it look that way. What you're looking to do is more of an orchestration task (ie when X do Y). There are ways of doing this with Puppet like using mcollective (to trigger a puppet run) which is managed by a webhook, but I think there are better tools for the job.

I'd suggest looking at [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [saltstack](http://saltstack.com/) or Chef's [knife tool](https://docs.chef.io/knife.html) to do deploys like this.

Comment: These adjustments are not very common - maybe a new site every couple of days, which is why I was thinking that in principle it's still declarative. I was just trying to avoid the time until the agent polls the master again.